# Embedded WebBrowser Control not respecting @media max-width attribute

Tags: css, internet-explorer

When I embed the WebBrowser control in a window using either Active-X or the .NET WebBrowser control (thin wrapper around the Active-X) control, it doesn't seem to respect **@media** css attributes such as **max-width**.  Given {[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WadeHatler/3mFB5/)}:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- necessary for tablets -->
    <style>
    #redBox  {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #blueBox {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
        #redBox {
            display: none;
            height: 0px;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="redBox">  Red Box  </div>
    <div id="blueBox"> Blue Box </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The red box should disappear when you make the window smaller than 1000px.

This works in Chrome, Firefox and IE.  However, when I load the page in a WebBrowser control using the .NET `WebBrowser` control, or a unmanaged application using the `Shell.Explorer` Active-X control, the change doesn't work.  It doesn't matter if I load it using a `file:///` attribute or with http.

Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`
in html.

Make sure you have IE9 or higher version.
WebBrowser control has all the functionality of Ie that is set up on local PC.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar Problem...

The only solution I can think of is a JavaScript-workaround, setting the desired CSS-attributes via JS depending on screen-width, for example screen.availWidth or such.